# jQuery delegate selector problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delegate click event to all first anchor tags of all now and future divs with "panels" class. I did something like that:

```
$('#panel').delegate('.panels a:first', 'click', function(event) [...]
```

but that doesn't work. It binds event only to one, first ".panels". Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this just with a selector, unless it happens that the `a` elements are not just the first anchor, but the first child of any kind inside the "panels" `div`s (in which case you can use `:first-child`).

You'll probably have to put some logic in the handler itself, to check that the anchor clicked is the *first* anchor in the `div`. Something along these lines:

```
$("#panel").delegate(".panels a", "click", function() {
  if ($(this).siblings("a").andSelf()[0] === this) {
    // It's the first anchor in its parent
  }
  return false;
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/idufid)

That works because `siblings` and `andSelf` both guarantee to keep the array inside the jQuery object in document order, so checking if `this` is the `[0]`th element works.

Comment: Yes, it's always first child in "panels", so :first-child is enough. You were faster, so in few minutes I'll mark your answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `:first-child`, `:first` only returns one element.

What you are doing now is equal to `$('.panels a').get(0)`

Source:
http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/